# GLUT GL 3/4 sphere something wrong

Tags: graphics, glut

I have task to do for my graphics lessons. I have to build 3/4 of using only GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP. I have already finished it, but there is one major bug that I cannot accept.

```
GLfloat radius = 3, alpha, beta, PI = 3.14314159;


//lHorizontal and lVertical im changing using keyboard it says how many 
 sphere divisions are 

for (alpha = 0.0; alpha < PI; alpha += PI / lVertical)
{

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);


    for (beta = 0.0; beta < 1.5075*PI; beta += PI / lHorizontal)
    {

        glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
        x = radius * cos(beta)*sin(alpha);
        y = radius * sin(beta)*sin(alpha);
        z = radius * cos(alpha);

        glNormal3f(x, y, z);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);

        glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
        x = radius * cos(beta)*sin(alpha + PI / lVertical);
        y = radius * sin(beta)*sin(alpha + PI / lVertical);
        z = radius * cos(alpha + PI / lVertical);

        glNormal3f(x, y, z);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);



    }
    glEnd();
}


glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

for (alpha = PI; alpha < 2.01*PI; alpha += PI / lVertical) {
    x = -radius * sin(alpha);
    y = 0;
    z = radius * cos(alpha);
    glNormal3f(x, y, z);
    glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
}
glEnd();


glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

for (alpha = PI; alpha < 2.01*PI; alpha += PI / lVertical) {
    x = 0;
    y = radius * sin(alpha);
    z = -radius * cos(alpha);
    glNormal3f(x, y, z);
    glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
}
glEnd();
```

The result of this code is:

[image: Correct one (pic)]

As Im changing lHorizontal appear piece that shouldnt be there (look at pic). What can i change in code to avoid this problem?

[image: Bugged one (pic)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of PI is wrong:

```
..., PI = 3.14314159; // 3.14159... ?
```

---

After correcting this, let's test the values of `alpha` in the outer loop, for `lVertical = 8`:

```
int lVertical = 8;
GLfloat radius = 3, alpha, beta, PI = 3.141592654;

for (alpha = 0.0; alpha < PI; alpha += PI / lVertical)
{
    printf("%f, %f\n", alpha, alpha + PI / lVertical);
}
```

Output:

```
0.000000, 0.392699
0.392699, 0.785398
0.785398, 1.178097
1.178097, 1.570796
1.570796, 1.963495
1.963495, 2.356194
2.356194, 2.748893
2.748893, 3.141593
3.141593, 3.534292 <<
```

`3.534292` is greater than `PI`, which means that it is an invalid value for `alpha`. The effect is that the last polygon ring "folds" around, producing the part that shouldn't be  there.

It is better to directly calculate the angles from an integer index:

```
for (int i = 0; int i < lVertical; i++)
{
    GLfloat alpha1 = (PI / lVertical) * i;
    GLfloat alpha2 = (PI / lVertical) * (i + 1);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int j = 0; j < lHorizontal; j++)
    {
        GLfloat beta1 = (PI / lHorizontal) * j;
        GLfloat beta2 = (PI / lHorizontal) * (j + 1);

        glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
        x = radius * cos(beta1)*sin(alpha1);
        y = radius * sin(beta1)*sin(alpha1);
        z = radius * cos(alpha1);

        glNormal3f(x, y, z);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);

        glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
        x = radius * cos(beta2)*sin(alpha2);
        y = radius * sin(beta2)*sin(alpha2);
        z = radius * cos(alpha2);

        glNormal3f(x, y, z);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    }

    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: @PawełKierski define "does not work". Can you post a picture of the result?